# DateTime in SQLServer and VB.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write the current date into a database table. I have set the field of the table as 'date'. I am writing

`DateTime.Now.Date.ToString` as a parameter to the insert/update query. So, my code is something like:

`cmd.CommandText = "update tab set dt = @d where id=1"
cmd.Parameters.add("@d",DateTime.Now.Date.ToString)`

This doesnt seem to be updating values in the database. Is something amiss here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't pass in a string to something that expects a `DATE`.

Pass in the `DateTime` instance instead:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d",DateTime.Now.Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL Server get remove the parameter and change the SPROC to use GETDATE() that will cause this to always insert the SQL Server's current DateTime Stamp.